# Do I need OpenGL in Ubuntu 22.04 to run Chrome?

Tags: drivers, google-chrome, opengl

I have been unable to run Chrome since upgrading to 22.04 on my HP Compaq dc7800p with Intel® Core™2 Duo CPU E8500 and Intel® Q35 Graphics. Chrome worked fine in 20.04. The link on Applications in 22.04 wouldn’t work. Downloading and installing the real Google Chrome didn't work. Uninstalled everything. Downloaded and reinstalled Google Chrome and got error messages primarily because “OpenGL ES 2.0 is not supportable.” “Intel or NVIDIA OpenGL ES drivers are not supported” also appears. Do I need to get OpenGL or just revert my old machine to 20.04?

Comment: I don't use `google-chrome` sorry, but I've not noted any issues with `chromium` (default repository version) on any any release of Ubuntu (or *flavors*) on hp dc7700, dc7800 or like boxes.

Comment: Thanks. For some reason it has started to work.